How to calculate expected value of softmax values in Tensorflow?
I have a model with a final softmax layer for N categories.  These categories are ordered and numerical, so it's meaningful to calculate statistics over the probability distribution given by softmax.
Assume the category values are simply an increasing index sequence.  So, the first has value 0, the second 1, etc.  I'd like to calculate the expected value (\sum_i=0^{N-1} i p_i).
How can I do this in Tensorflow as an additional output layer (of dimension 1)? Perhaps using frozen weights (0 to N-1)? I can then apply a loss to this output value.
Alternatively, if an output as part of the model architecture is not possible, then how could I implement this in a loss class? This would require something like tf.ones_like() to fill a tensor along an axis with increasing integers (0 to N-1).

You can just use tf.range, multiply with the probabilites, and sum.

As per the question's speculation, the mean can be implemented using frozen weights assigned the values of the category labels.  In this example, those were [0, N-1]:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Softmax

probs = Softmax()(logits)

mean = Dense(1, use_bias=False, trainable=False,
             kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(
                 np.arange(N)) )(probs)

